# What complications could arise from Jersey MultiException?

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0

I have a Jersey REST endpoint which has a PathParam that I need to validate before any method can proceed. Below is a code sample of just a GET,  though imagine there's also a POST, a PUT, DELETE, etc. each requiring that the "order_id" in the path is validated.

Instead, one could have like the below, that the @PathParam annotation is applied to a method which throws a 404 if the "order_id" does not exist.

However, when an exception occurs before the @GET method is called, a Jersey MultiException is thrown, the first is the NotFoundException in the validate method below, and the second is "IllegalStateException" because the @GET method could not be called.

Currently, the result is a proper 404 response, though I worry that this is not consistent. Is this an acceptable pattern? Are there any side effects that bring about concern?

```
@Path("/orders/{order_id}/items")
public ItemsResource {

  @Inject
  private OrderService orderService;

  private String orderId;

  @PathParam("order_id")
  private void validateAndSetOrderId(String orderId) {
    if (orderService.getOrder(orderId) == null) {
      throw new NotFoundException("Order not found.");
    }
    this.orderId = orderId;
  }

  @GET
  public Response getItems() {
    // could validate the order_id here if @PathParam were on the variable
    return orderService.getItems(this.orderId);
  }
}
```